# ReactNative & Expo: Trouble incrementing/decrementing to cycle through an Array

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, expo, mobile-development

I am attempting to cycle through sound objects in an Array, using an index value that begins at 0 and increments/decrements depending on whether I press next or back.

This is for a music player for react-native using the Expo//expo-av library. I'll include all relevant code.

State I have in my Context file:

```
const initialState = {
  startMusic: () => null,
  stopMusic: () => null,
  soundObject: null,
  isPlaying: false,
  currentIndex: 0,
}
useState()
const [soundObject, setSoundObject] = useState(initialState.soundObject)
const [isPlaying, setIsPlaying] = useState(initialState.isPlaying)
const [currentIndex, setCurrentIndex] = useState(initialState.currentIndex)
```

Start Music function

```
const startMusic = async () => {
    try {
      const songToPlay = songs[currentIndex].song
      const source = songs[currentIndex].path

      await songToPlay.loadAsync(source)
      await songToPlay.playAsync()
      setSoundObject(songToPlay)
      setIsPlaying(true)
      return new Promise(resolve => {      // I made this promise when I was setting a loop to play through music.  May not need this anymore
        songToPlay.setOnPlaybackStatusUpdate(playbackStatus => {
          if (playbackStatus.didJustFinish) {
            console.log("Song finished")
            resolve()
          }
        })
      })
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(`Error: ${error}`)
      return
    }
  }
```

And finally, the handler functions that are supposed to cycle through songs:

```
const handlePreviousTrack = async () => {
    if (soundObject) {
      await soundObject.stopAsync()
      await soundObject.unloadAsync()
      // setSoundObject(null)
      let newIndex = currentIndex

      newIndex < songs.length - 1 ? newIndex-- : (newIndex = 0)

      setCurrentIndex(newIndex)
      startMusic()

      console.log(currentIndex)
    }
  }

  const handleNextTrack = async () => {
    if (soundObject) {
      await soundObject.stopAsync()
      await soundObject.unloadAsync()
      // setSoundObject(null)
      let newIndex = currentIndex

      newIndex < songs.length - 1 ? newIndex++ : (newIndex = 0)

      setCurrentIndex(newIndex)
      startMusic()

      console.log(currentIndex)
    }
  }
```

Cycling through next/previous does not go in order. 
Sometimes it works, sometimes previous goes to the next song, sometimes pressing next just replays the first song.

Am I manipulating the state via currentIndex incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything alarmingly wrong in the above code by quickly looking through it.  One suggestion I would have is to take your `startMusic()` call out of your two `handleTrack` methods and instead just have them set index state as they are doing.

Instead add a `useEffect` that will fire every time the index changes and put your `startMusic()` in that useEffect.

It would look something like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
   ... (other logic)
   startMusic()
}, [currentIndex])
```

This will ensure startMusic will only get called after the currentIndex state has been changed and not be called too soon etc.  If not it may make it easier to track down when the state is changing regardless

Comment: How much of it should I wrap in useEffect()?  I just tried a few different ways but it actually stops the next/prev functions from playing music.

Comment: I'd imagine it would work as specified above with just the `startMusic()` try console logging the currentIndex above startMusic to see when it is running and if that is being set properly in the other functions